# How to loop through a range until a cell is empty In Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to piece together a solution for a problem with Excel and VBA that I've been working on for work. Full disclosure: I'm not really a developer and am really struggling with it - even if it is very simple(!) An example of my problem is below:

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqf30.png)

In the above table I paste values that take up columns A to C from another Workbook into the bottom of this one. I also have formula in columns D and E which processes the information in columns A to C.

Ordinarily I would Copy the formulae in row 2 of columns D and E and Paste it down column D to process the new values pasted into A to C. Then, I Refresh the Workbook as I have Pivot tables summarising the data in columns D and E. Finally, I would Save the changes to the Workbook.

I've been trying to automate this process and have cobbled together something to do the above, but when I run my project, I produce the 'Run-time error: 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error.'

Any help with the below would be a huge help and greatly appreciated.

Thank you

```
Sub Button1_Click()

'Step 1: Copy Range
Range("D2:E2").Copy

'Step 2: Move to row after last with formula in column D
Range("D" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select

'Step 2: Paste formula
Call Paste_formula

'Step 3: Refresh Pivot table
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

'Step 4: Save Workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub


Sub Paste_formula()

'Declare variables and set their types
Dim r As Range
Dim CurrRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

'Execute a series of statements in the 'Data' Worksheet
With Sheets("Data")
    'Set variable's values
    CurrRow = ActiveCell.Row
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'For Loop which establishes the range for r being between the last row with Data in column D and the last row with Data in column A
    For Each r In .Range(CurrRow, LastRow)
        'In every row there is a remuneration data in column A
        If r.Value <> "" Then
        ' ...select the respective cell in column D...
            r.Offset(0, 4).Select
            ' ...and paste the current selection
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: what range are you actually trying to loop? Column A from where to where?

Comment: Is it sheet Data in both subs?

Comment: Hi,

From the first cell in column A with no value in the same Row in column D (in the example: third row of the table) to the last row with a value in column A (in the example: fifth row of the table)

Thanks,

Comment: But is the sheet always the same you are working with?

Comment: Yes it is, everything is done in the 'Data' Sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering if something like the following but are you changing sheets and still expecting to be working with the prior ActiveCell?

```
Sub Paste_formula()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim CurrRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Sheets("Data")

        CurrRow = ActiveCell.Row
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For Each r In .Range("A" & CurrRow & ":A" & LastRow)

            If r.Value <> vbNullString Then r.Offset(0, 4) = r

        Next r

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patience. The above changes have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
For Each r In .Range(CurrRow, LastRow)
```

to:

```
For Each r In .Range(.Cells(LastRow, "A").Cells(CurrRow, "D"))
```

According to what you wrote in your code's comments and your current code.

Comment: I'm afraid when I try to run using the above, it still returns the 1004 run-time error.

If it's of any help in debug mode, the LastRow variable contains a value of 5, the CurrRow variable contains a value of 3, but r contains 'nothing'.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's greatly appreciated.